# What does mean by a Topological closure $ F' \ $ of a field $ \ F \ $ with respect to a norm $ \ ||.|| \ $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

What does mean by a Topological closure $ F' \ $ of a field $ \ F \ $ with respect to a norm $ \ ||.|| \ $ ?

**Answer:**

I know the closure of a subset S of points in a topological space consists of all points in S together with all limit points of S.

But i can't explain what is meant by topological closure of a field ?

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What is the context here? Is $F$ an arbitrary field or do we know more?

Comment: Specifically, the obvious context in which this makes sense is if $F$ is naturally contained within some larger normed field, is this true here?

Comment: I can't find any support for this, but I'm throwing it out to see if it rings true with anyone else. A topology could be said to be closed with respect to a norm if it contains all finite unions and intersections of balls under the metric derived from the norm.

Comment: Here $ \ F \ $ is p-adic field ?

Comment: The only thing that makes sense to me, in that case, is that we're talking about the metric completion. "Topological closure" would be an odd way to refer to that, though.